# tcpdump on a capture card

Tags: tcpdump, packet-capture, sfp

I have a server with a NT20E Capture Card (2x10Gb Packet Capture Card over PCI Express). I want to be able to dump the output to a pcap format but because this isn't listed as an ethX-interface tcpdump is unable to capture data.

My question now: how am I able to dump the data that this card receives on it's interfaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this mail message to the Wireshark-dev mailing list](http://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-dev/201210/msg00090.html) "[Napatech provides] a custom libpcap that works with their card (and wire/tshark)."  It should work with tcpdump as well.  If you have questions about it. the best thing to do would be to contact Napatech.

Comment: I found this the best answer. I solved it by downloading another napatech driver and by putting it in OSmode (it's a configuration flag). Thanks anyway!